# Npm install ignores tilde (~) in version number

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I would like to install 1.8.x version a package, and be able to later automatically update this dependency inside the >=1.8.0 <1.9.0 range.

I tried to run this command:

```
npm install example-package@~1.8 --save
```

Unfortunately it adds this record to my `package.json`:

```
"example-package" : "^1.8.0"
```

But what I want is this:

```
"example-package" : "~1.8.0"
```

How is it possible to do it with `npm install`, without manually edit the `package.json` file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The semver prefix is defined by the [`save-prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/config.html#save-prefix) config. The default value is a caret (`^`) which you can check by running the following [`npm config`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) command:

```
npm config get save-prefix
```

Unfortunately, the [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) command has no option to specify this, so what you'll need to do is:

1. Set the `save-prefix` value to a tilde (`~`) by running:

   ```
   npm config set save-prefix="~"
   ```
2. Install your package by running:

   ```
   npm i example-package@1.8.0 --save
   ```

   **Note:** The tilde (`~`) must not be included in the install command.
3. Finally, set the `save-prefix` value back to it's default, i.e. a caret (`^`) by running:

   ```
   npm config delete save-prefix
   ```

   **Note:** You wouldn't do this last step if you wanted all future `npm install`'s to use the tilde (`~`) prefix instead of a caret (`^`).

The above steps will add the following record in `package.json`:

```json
"example-package" : "~1.8.0"
```

<sub>Note the tilde `~` instead of the default caret `^`</sub>

---

You can utilize the `&&` operator to combine the aforementioned commands into a compound command. For instance:

```
npm config set save-prefix="~" && npm i example-package@1.8.0 --save && npm config delete save-prefix
```