# npm: How to install the latest patch release of a package?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I would like to install the latest patch release of Typescript 3.7 (now it is 3.7.5) using `npm i -D typescript<...>` command. It should be also installed after downloading the project from GitHub and running `npm i`.

That means that package.json should preferably contain this line:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "typescript": "~3.7.5"
}
```

The typescript package should update to 3.7.6 in the future if there will be such version, but not to already existing 3.8.0 nor 3.9.0 versions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the; _"It should be also installed after downloading the project from GitHub"_ part of your question. However, if you are wanting to download the package from the npm registry you can run the following compound command: `npm config set save-prefix="~" && npm i -D typescript@3.7.5 && npm config delete save-prefix` - my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864514/npm-install-ignores-tilde-in-version-number/60865320#60865320) provides and explanation to the aforementioned command(s).

Comment: @RobC Thank you, that's exactly what I meant.