# How to install npm package from command line with tilda~?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I want to install typescript in specific version and save the version to `package.json`:

```
"typescript": "~3.9.3"
```

Of course I can do it by write `"typescript": "~3.9.3"` in package.json and then run `npm i`.

But I want to install by cmd and then npm will update the `package.json` with the version I specified.

something like:

```
npm i typescript@~3.9.3 --save-dev
```

but its not work cause in the `package.json` npm write:

```
"typescript": "^3.9.7"
```

I want npm to write:

```
"typescript": "~3.9.3"
```

How can I achieve that with npm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm install ignores tilde (~) in version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864514/npm-install-ignores-tilde-in-version-number)

Comment: no. the prefix set the tilda but in package json it write wrong version: 3.9.7

Comment: in package json, I have `~3.9.7` (after installed). try yourself.

Comment: Assuming you want `"typescript": "~3.9.3"` in _package.json_ you need to run: `npm config set save-prefix="~" && npm i typescript@3.9.3 --save-dev && npm config delete save-prefix`

Comment: Running the compound command given in my earlier comment, then running `npm ls typescript` lists `typescript@3.9.3` as the version that was installed. Also it adds `"typescript": "~3.9.3"` the to the `devDependencies` section in _package,json_. What compound command did you run to get `~3.9.7` ?

Comment: Sorry but I do as you say, still I get "~3.9.7" version